TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tokenType')
We're getting the following error when trying to embed a report with the Power BI Angular library.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tokenType')
    at isSaaSEmbedWithAADToken (reportEmbed?navContentPaneEnabled=false&uid=ame7c8:586:38)
    at getModelsAndExploration (reportEmbed?navContentPaneEnabled=false&uid=ame7c8:696:17)
    at getModelsAndExplorationAndConceptualSchema (reportEmbed?navContentPaneEnabled=false&uid=ame7c8:840:9)
    at xhr.onreadystatechange (reportEmbed?navContentPaneEnabled=false&uid=ame7c8:505:37)

This is code which we are using to embed the report.
this.msalService.initialize().subscribe(() => {
      this.msalService.acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: environment.powerBiConfig.scopes,
        account: this.authService.getUser()
      }).subscribe(async (result) => {
        const embedConfig: pbi.service.IComponentEmbedConfiguration = {
          type: 'report',
          id: this.report.identifier,
          accessToken: result.accessToken,
          tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
          embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?navContentPaneEnabled=false',
          settings: {
            panes: {
              filters: {
                visible: false,
              }
            }
          }
        };
        const defaultFilters = this.createDefaultFilters();
        const powerBiReport: any = this.powerBiService.embed(this.reportContainer.nativeElement, embedConfig);
        powerBiReport.on('loaded', async () => {
          await powerBiReport.setFilters(defaultFilters);
        });
      });
    });

After following the stacktrace into Power BI Embedded JS files (which we have no control of), we were able to determine what's causing the issue.
The following function expects a config to be passed:
function isSaaSEmbedWithAADToken(config) {
    // Default token type is Aad (0)
    const tokenType = config.tokenType || 0;
    return (window.isSaasOrPaasEmbed === true) && (tokenType === 0);
}

However the piece of code that's causing the error is not actually passing the config.
if (isSaaSEmbedWithAADToken() && config.settings && config.settings.personalBookmarksEnabled) {
    url += "&defaultBookmarkEnabled=true";
}

Even if we're doing something wrong on our end, this is a bug at Microsoft's end. The fix is simply passing the config like other parts of the code are already doing.
Is there something wrong in our setup which is causing this issue? The Power BI Embedded JS files seem to be closed source.

We recently started seeing this issue in our embeds as well. We noticed that the embed code works in spite of the error in the latest version of chromium but fails in older version of chrome (~80). Unfortunately we have to make this work in the older version of chromium. @Stephan any chance you could be using the older version of chromium as well?

I was able to verify that the embed code works for version 94 and onwards. I have a feeling that this error is unrelated to the issue.

@SubaS I'm using an up-to-date version of Chrome (125.x.x), this issue is non-blocking for newer version of Chromium.
Reports are now loading at our end, we had another issue which was causing our reports to not load. But still, the fact remains that there seems to be a bug in the code on Microsoft's side.

hi @StephanBisschop which was the other issue that caused reports not to load?, because in older browsers this started to happen a few days ago and the only error in console is the one you've reported. thanks!

It's happening as well to me, although I have the embed option and doesn't affect my users. Found this thread on microsoft https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/TypeError-Cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-tokenType/m-p/3983570

This issue has been fixed. Please refer to the following github issue:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tokenType') · Issue #66 · microsoft/powerbi-client-angular · GitHub

The error does not appear anymore but the embedded report still does not appear in chromium version older than 94.

Issue has been fixed at Microsoft's end.
https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-client-angular/issues/66
